# IE11 two audio tag only one works

Tags: internet-explorer-11, html5-audio

```js
function playsound(item) {
  var itemToPlay = document.getElementById(item);
  itemToPlay.play();
}
```

```html
<button onclick="playsound('audio_login')">simulate login</button>
<button onclick="playsound('audio_logout')">simulate logout</button>
<audio id="audio_login">
 <source src="sounds/toctoc.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
<audio id="audio_logout">
 <source src="sounds/logout.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

This very simple example is correctly executed in Chrome (ver 81), Firefox(ver 76) both in localhost and server version (https://www.gdfclub.it/pages/test/audiotest.html).
In IE11 instead it works in localhost while in the server version only one audio is played (the second one).
What am I terribly wrong??
I looked for similar questions but found only cases where the audio tag does not work at all in IE11, and not only partially!

Comment: Your example works for me in IE11.

Comment: I test the server version in IE 11 and both of the buttons can work well. What is your IE 11 version number? Have you used F12 dev tools to debug the page? Is there any error in console? Besides, you could clear browser cache and try again.

Comment: I have win8.1
Bryan: I tried on IE11 on another machine with win10 and it actually works.

YuZhou: Version: 11.0.9600.19573
Update version: 11.0.165 (KB4530677).Yes, I tried to clear the cache but the problem persists. No messages in the console (I think it is due to the fact that play() method does not return any value..).

Comment: I also tried on IE in win10 and my IE version is 11.778.18362.0, update version 11.0.185. Maybe there's some issue with the lower version of IE 11 in win8. You could try to update the IE 11 to the latest version in win8 or try to [reset IE 11](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17441/windows-internet-explorer-change-reset-settings) in win8 and try again.

Comment: I was unable to find a way to update IE11. For me the important thing is to know that the problem is due to a bug from a previous version and therefore I can be satisfied. Thank you all

Comment: You're welcome. By the way, you can update IE by installing Windows update.